# JDBC PreparedStatement and parameters (?) in select query

Tags: java, oracle, parameters, prepared-statement

I have a connection with oracle database like this:

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT ?,supplier_name FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "supplier_id");
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1);
        ResultSet rs2 = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs2.next()) {
            String userid = rs2.getString(1);
            String username = rs2.getString(2);
            System.out.println(userid);
            System.out.println(username);
        }
        con.close();
    };
```

The problem is that the second parameter is passed like I want which means that

> supplier_id = 1

but I have a problem with the first parameter. Each time only the string is beeing passed so my query looks like

> select "supplier_id", supplier_name FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id =
>   ?

instead of

> select supplier_id, supplier_name FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id = 
>   ?

Because of that as a result I don't get the value from the table coressponding to supplier_id but the string "supplier_id".
What am I doing wrong? What should I change to get the value not string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to create dynamic queries this way, you have to use the normal string operations. Parameters can only be used for values, like Strings, Numbers, etc., not for names.

In your case it would be possible to do something like

```
String sqlTemplate = "SELECT <id_column>,supplier_name FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id = ?";
String selectSQL = sqlTemplate.replace("<id_column>", "supplier_id");
```

Comment: what does it mean normal string operations?

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide an example

Comment: now its very clear to me :) Thank you very much, you are awesome :)